# Java inheritance How to differentiate type of user in a program?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, authentication

So I'm making a system with a login that gives the user different options depending on what type of user they are.

e.g [image]

Im wondering how I should make the system differentiate between the two at login. Do i give the user class a Boolean type check for each type of user?

e.g booleanUser1Check() and booleanUser2Check()

or an userType id Attribute.

What is the best way to do this in terms of oop?

Comment: Sales extends User, Manager extends Sales ?, Not sure why Manager would not extend Sales

Comment: just an example. could be cat extends animal and doge extends animal.

Comment: "Polymorphism" is the right answer.  Generally you should not try to invent your own type system with IDs or ints.  Rely on the Java types to do the job.  Anything else is probably broken.  However the idea of using an `enum` as below is probably re-inventing the wheel and I don't care for it.

Comment: "how I should make the system differentiate between the two at login" you shouldn't! Instead they should **behave** differently while "the system" treats them the same, that's the whole point of polymorphism, if you do actually need to differentiate between them use `instanceof` no need for an `enum`

Comment: @markspace How would you discriminate between the types, `instanceof`?

Comment: Is using instanceOf good practice when they are stored as Users in a collection?

Comment: No, `instanceof` is not good practice it's a last resort

Comment: `instanceOf` is generally a bad practice.

Comment: @Oleg  Thats what i was taught. what would be a better alternative in this situation?

Comment: @ConnorJones Proper OO design, instead of checking what kind of user you have and doing something based on that, encapsulate the behavior in `User` and it's subclasses(or another class using some design pattern) this way you change the behavior for different User types while the code that uses your different Users remains the same.

Comment: @ConnorJones See updated answer

Comment: If you have code that differentiates each subclass, the code to differentiate them should be in the class definition. You should not build another class that must know explicit details about your implementation class, or else you break the idea of OO by not adhering to only interacting with the object through public methods. Classes that deal with your object should not need to know about it's subclass implementations.

Comment: @MeetTitan would  you suggest use a getType() method in my base class, override that method in my user sub classes to return a value based on what type of user has logged in?

Comment: No, you should have a `user.LoggedIn()` method in your subclass that you define in your subclass if you want class specific behavior in your subclasses that can be called the exact same as the superclass (even with superclass syntax! Hint hint). This is called polymorphism.

Comment: I've edited my question to further explain how to better use *polymorphism* in your program's context. Ideally, you shouldn't need to know the user's type, but have all the users behaviour encapsulated inside the classes that define them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at existing authorization frameworks you'll notice that none of them use polymorphism for defining access control restrictions. Instead each user is represented by an instance of the same class and the instance has properties that defines the user's access rights. These properties are often called roles and they represent real life human roles like administrator, user, sales lead, etc.

In most systems a user can even have multiple roles, for example if a user is a "developer" and a "manager" at the same time.

This allows you to create an unlimited number of role combinations in configuration files. With a polymorphic approach you have to define every single one in code. Having to change code and make a release every time user roles change increases your maintenance cost considerably.

Comment: Assuming this is a small system that only requires Admin, student and teacher with a user base class. where users will never take on multiple roles. How would you differentiate without using instanceof or having the user specifying its type(e.g through dropdown menu) on login?

Comment: Users are assigned a role when they are registered into the system. Each action that can be performed in the system is configured with a role that is required before it can be called. E.g. a user with only role "student" can not perform an operation that requires "teacher" role. If a user does not have a required role, the action is denied. It's the most simple comparison: if (user.getRoles().contains(requiredRole) { ... }. Where it gets interesting is when you start defining the required roles in annotations and start automating the access control. :)

Answer (score 0):

An interesting way to achieve what you want is to take advantage of *polymorphism*, that is, the ability of an object to take on many forms. Among other things, this feature allows a parent class reference variable to refer to an instance of one of its children classes. See below how you can do it.

Create an abstract class that will define the default structure for all the users:

```
public abstract class User
{
    private String name;
    private String email;

    //...
    //perform an action that must have a different behaviour for each user type
    public abstract void doSomething();
}
```

Note that you can declare both abstract and non-abstract methods there. Now, create a class for each type of user:

```
public class Admin extends User
{
    //...
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
       //action's behaviour for an admin
    }
}

public class NormalUser extends User
{
    //...
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
       //action for a normal user
    }
}

public class PremiumUser extends User
{
    //...
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
       //action for a premium user
    }
}
```

Remember that all classes that *extends* `User` must implement its abstract methods (`doSomething()` in this case). Now, if you really need to know the user's type, use the operator *instaceof* to check whether a variable of the type `User`contains an instance of one of the classes above. See an example below:

```
User user = ...
if(user instanceof NormalUser) {
    //user is a normal user
} 
//...
```

Note, however, that **a better and more object oriented design would be to have the parent class handle the general actions needed for an user and let the children classes fill in the specifics**. In the example above, all users can perform an action as defined by `doSomething()`, but the action is different for each user. Since each user type implements this method differently, you can use it without the need of knowing what type the user is.

This way you encapsulate the behaviour in `User` and its subclasses, so that the code used for different users is the same, even though their behaviour differ. See below:

```
User user = ...
user.doSomething(); //perform different actions depending on the user's type. Notice that you do not need to know what type the user is in this case
```

Comment: This breaks the single responsibility principle in a major way by moving UI code directly into access management code. This is the way to spaghetti code.

Comment: My example was unfortunate, indeed, however it was merely there to illustrate the main idea (*polymorphism*). Anyway, I've changed it for something else. Thanks for pointing it out.